# Dependent method types and type-classes

Tags: scala, dependent-method-type, typeclass

I've got a bunch of data store type-classes that look all the same.

```
trait FooStore[C] {
  def create(f: FooId => Foo)(c: C): Foo
  // update and find methods
}
```

I'd like to simplify things and was hoping to use dependent method types to get something closer to

```
sealed trait AR {
  type Id
  type Type
}

sealed trait FooAR extends AR {
  type Id = FooId
  type Type = Foo
}

trait DataStore[C] {
  def create(ar: AR)(f: ar.Id => ar.Type)(c: C): ar.Type
}
```

but when I try and create an instance of that as follows

```
case class InMemory(foos: List[Foo])
object InMemory {
  lazy val InMemoryDataStore: DataStore[InMemory] = new DataStore[InMemory] {
    def create(ar: AR)(f: ar.Id => ar.Type)(c: InMemory): ar.Type = sys.error("not implemented")
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error

```
object creation impossible, since method create in trait DataStore of type (ar: AR)(f: ar.Id => ar.Type)(c: InMemory)ar.Type is not defined
  lazy val InMemoryDataStore: DataStore[InMemory] = new DataStore[InMemory] {
                                                        ^
one error found
```

I don't understand since that method is pretty clearly defined on the `DataStore` instance.  What does the error mean and is this possible?  If not, is there a different way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: just checking... are you compiling with `-Ydependent-method-types`?

Comment: @mergeconflict: yes, compiling with dependent method types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It compiles using the Scala-2.10-M2 milestone, some dependent method type bugs have been fixed since the 2.9 release. I'm not completely sure, but perhaps [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5033) might have made it work.

Comment: I agree with @Arjan ... it works for me with the latest 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT, and SI-5033 does look likely as the culprit.

Comment: Great!  Thanks guys!  What about the 2.9.2 RC?  I don't have an environment up to test that easily.  Guess I'll have to get one soon.